# Which of these methods is recommended for connecting to MongoDB in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Method 1:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
DB db = mongo.getDB("db");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
```

Method 2:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("db");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");
```

Which is the preferred method and why? What are the advantages to either method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [Mongo](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) is superseeded by [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) and may be deprecated in future releases.

That means you should use MongoClient.

The main difference is the default write concern. Mongo defaulted to unacknowledged while MongoClient defaults to acknowledged. But even when you want unacknowledged write concerns to be the default, you should still use MongoClient with an appropriate [MongoClientOptions](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html) object to make sure your application still builds when a future version of the Java driver removes the Mongo class.

Additionally, the MongoClient gives you access to an overhauled API with `MongoDatabase` instead of `DB` and `MongoCollection<TDocument>` instead of `DBCollection` which you might find to allow you to write more readable code.